# What interactions between a bot and the chat system are allowed?

Tags: discussion, chat

This is somewhat related to [Are bots specifically allowed or prohibited in Stack Exchange chatrooms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116589/are-bots-specifically-allowed-or-prohibited-in-stack-exchange-chatrooms).

Most of the "bots" I've seen are javascript that are run in a persons web browser using their login as a form of authorisation (so act as a automated script, rather than a separate entity).

I've written one that uses Python and interfaces directly with the chat system using WebSockets (and the SE system using the API) using its own account - the initial purpose was to develop a relay system to push to an IRC channel). This has extended to being a fun "chat bot" (which is now disabled) and to looking at new posts in certain tags that are potentially spam... (this isn't public at the moment, and more a log report, but hoping to improve on this, and and build up a better learning set).

The main question I have, isn't if it's explicitly allowed or disallowed, but rather what's acceptable for use:

- is it okay to "log" the channel (it is public chat after all and googleable?)
- it it okay to allow it to automate room owner commands such as moving posts from a user
- what is a really practicable non-bannable limit for retrieving posts for analysis

Let me know if I can clarify any futher...

Comment: Chat rooms have transcripts; you don't need a bot to log a room; just grab the transcripts whenever you want them yourself.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't arguing that point - yes, I can access the transcripts - but is it okay for one to store them

Comment: If you really want to store them just ping the transcript once a day or so, rather than creating a bot to sit in the chatroom listening to every single message sent.

Comment: @Servy I don't get deleted messages, I also don't get it useful as a tool in realtime

Comment: I'm probably missing some reference or something but what's `"bots"Mos` in the title?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that "bot" was intended as the end of the title, and the Mos came from a mistaken paste of the content into the title field before they added the "This is somewhat related" line.